# parse xml file with game data in python

Tags: python

I have this game data written in xml format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<log xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://mirror.server.eu/descr.xsd">
        <version>0.1</version>
        <info>
                <timestamp>2018-09-23 16:09:23 CEST</timestamp>
                <hostname>server.eu</hostname>
        </info>
        <events>
                <event>
                        <pickup>
                                <time>1.506636</time>
                                <item>item_spikes</item>
                                <player>player1</player>
                                <value>50</value>
                        </pickup>
                </event>
                <event>
                        <damage>
                                <time>1.926975</time>
                                <attacker>player1</attacker>
                                <target>player2</target>
                                <type>sg</type>
                                <quad>0</quad>
                                <splash>0</splash>
                                <value>24</value>
                                <armor>0</armor>
                        </damage>
                </event>
                <event>
                        <death>
                                <time>4.862534</time>
                                <attacker>player2</attacker>
                                <target>player1</target>
                                <type>lg_beam</type>
                                <quad>0</quad>
                                <armorleft>0</armorleft>
                                <killheight>0</killheight>
                                <lifetime>4.862534</lifetime>
                        </death>
                </event>
        </events>
</log>
```

I need to parse it and take out all events called 'death'. Then I need to access every element in that 'death' section. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post that code and where you are facing a problem, add that too in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that events can only contain a tag called death you can easily do this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='your_game_events.xml')
for event in tree.iter(tag = 'death'):
    for child in event:
        print "%s: %s" % (child.tag, child.text)
```